# What is the default search engine going to be in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, search-engines

Once Windows 7 finally ships in October, what's the default search engine going to be in Internet Explorer? Also, are there going to be any other web browsers installed by default (seems silly to me that MS would include anything but IE, but I still wanted to ask this for the community's sake).

Thanks in advance for all your helpful responses!

Yasser

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Europe, you can [choose what browser to install](http://microsoftontheissues.com/cs/blogs/mscorp/archive/2009/07/31/windows-7-and-browser-choice-in-europe.aspx). In the US, Internet Explorer is installed by default.

The default search engine for Internet Explorer is Bing.

Answer (score 1):

What I can say from Windows 7 Professional for Volume Licence Costumers the default search engine in IE is Bing. And in this version there are no other browsers included, but I don't know how this will change (eventually) in Windows 7 shipping on October 22nd.

Comment: Windows 7 Pro RTM is the same.

Answer (score 0):

In the European version of the Windows 7 you will be able to select an alternate browser. If you go with IE the default search provider is Bing.